# i am trying to add 2 queries at the same time using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know what is the problem with my query
i want to add a specific range, then add the id of the range to the table of items within the same form

```
$range_info = array (
    'min_price' => $_POST['min_price'],
    'max_price' => $_POST['max_price']
);

$item_info = array (
'item_name'   => $_POST['item_name'],
'cat_id'      => $cat_id,
'total_quantity'    => $_POST['total_quantity'],
'available_for_sale' => $_POST['available_for_sale'],
'description' => $_POST['desc'],
'user_id'   => $data['user_id']
 );

$range_fields = '`' . implode("`, `", array_keys($range_info)) . '`';
$range_data = '\'' . implode("', '", $range_info) . '\'';

$fields = '`' . implode("`, `", array_keys($item_info)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode("', '", $item_info) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO range($range_fields) VALUES ($range_data); INSERT 
INTO items($fields, `range_id`) VALUES ($data, '".mysql_insert_id()."'");
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries. And stop using `mysql_*` it is deprecated.

Comment: I've flagged this as unclear. What kind of output are you actually expecting from this?

Comment: @ArtOsi is right, and your code is very vulnerable to SQL Injection!

Comment: This question implies a lack of understanding of best practise, but for a script for an admin on a machine with no external access this might the shortest path to solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your queries (and you forgot to close a parentheses) here :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO range($range_fields) VALUES ($range_data)");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items($fields, `range_id`) VALUES ($data, '".mysql_insert_id()."')");
```

Note that your queries **are insecure**! try to **sanitize** the data of your post before using it or use **prepared statements** with `mysqli` or move to **PDO** instead!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, and i will sanitize all data right now!

Answer (score 0):

Store the insert queries into a separate variable and run

```
$range_info = array (
    'min_price' => $_POST['min_price'],
    'max_price' => $_POST['max_price']
);

$item_info = array (
  'item_name'          => $_POST['item_name'],
  'cat_id'             => $cat_id,
  'total_quantity'     => $_POST['total_quantity'],
  'available_for_sale' => $_POST['available_for_sale'],
  'description'        => $_POST['desc'],
  'user_id'            => $data['user_id']
);

$range_fields = '`' . implode("`, `", array_keys($range_info)) . '`';
$range_data   = '\'' . implode("', '", $range_info) . '\'';

$fields       = '`' . implode("`, `", array_keys($item_info)) . '`';
$data         = '\'' . implode("', '", $item_info) . '\'';

/*insert queries*/

$qr1 = "INSERT INTO range($range_fields) VALUES ($range_data)";
$qr2 = "INSERT INTO items($fields, `range_id`) VALUES ($data, '".mysql_insert_id()."')";
mysql_query($qr1);
mysql_query($qr2);
```

Note:

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

MySQLi tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_mysqli_connect.asp